# How to i can access two values in one template in kendo UI in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

```
<kendo-grid-column field="[_id,role]" title="Action"> 
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                  <!-- <span *ngIf="dataItem.ProductID == 1" class="badge badge-success">Online</span> -->
                  <button  class="btn btn-success m-2" style="width: 70px;"  (click)="openDialog(dataItem._id,dataItem.role)" > select Role</button>
              </ng-template>
              </kendo-grid-column>
```

here I want to get two values _id, role in function Can you please advice me how to I can get both value in function  .

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this issues we can simply get two value like follows

```
<kendo-grid-column field="_id" title="Action"> 
                <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                  <!-- <span *ngIf="dataItem.ProductID == 1" class="badge badge-success">Online</span> -->
                  <button  class="btn btn-success m-2" style="width: 70px;"  (click)="openDialog(dataItem._id,dataItem.role)" > select Role</button>
              </ng-template>
              </kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).